# Is there any standard way to handle fractions of bilinear constraints in optimization?

Tags: optimization

By fractional bilinear constraints, I mean this form:

$$\frac{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots}{b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \cdots} \frac{c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + \cdots}{d_1 + d_2 + d_3 + \cdots}$$

Here, $a,b,c,d$ are variables of the optimization.

Comment: What you've written there is the product of two fractions. What is the constraint exactly?

Comment: That is the constraint. That equal to a constant is the constraint.

Comment: Then it's equivalent to $(a_1+a_2+\cdots)(c_1+c_2+\cdots) = \mathrm{const}\cdot(b_1+b_2+\cdots)(d_1+d_2+\cdots)$, which is a quadratic constraint.

Comment: Alright. That is simply a bilinear constant then. A variation: what if the other side is not a constant but one of the variables?

Comment: What kind of function of the variables is the right hand side?

Comment: Perhaps geometric programming can help you.